# How to create Tensorflow data ingestion pipeline for multiple related CSVs?

Tags: tensorflow, relational-database, tensorflow2.0

Let us say we have some Relational data.
Making a simple example for a retail store chain:

- Dataset 1 --> Store_id, Daily_sales
- Dataset 2 --> Customer_id, store_id, Time in, Time out

Let us say the task is to predict `Daily_sales`.

I know how how to create data batches for one single CSV. I can use `tf.data.experimental.make_csv_dataset` and iterate over the dataset iterable that it returns to read the batches lazily.

However, I want to read in the batches from `Dataset 1` and `Dataset 2` described above where the common id is `store_id` such that the batch reads the rows with same `store_id`s from both the datasets. I want to do this because I will run two networks (RNN on `Dataset 2` and a single Fully connected layer on `Dataset 1`) on both datasets and then merge them in the final fully connected layer.

Can you please guide me on how to approach this problem in scenarios where:

- The datasets can fit into the memory
- The datasets can not fit into the memory

Here is a concrete example of the consistent batch creation I am looking  for:

```
import pandas as pd
Dataset_1 = pd.DataFrame({'id':['a','b','c','d'],'col1':[1,2,3,4]})
print(Dataset_1)
  id  col1
0  a     1
1  b     2
2  c     3
3  d     4
Dataset_2 = pd.DataFrame({'id':['a','a','b','c','c','c','d'],'col1':[10,11,12,13,14,15,16]})
print(Dataset_2)
    id  col1
0   a   10
1   a   11
2   b   12
3   c   13
4   c   14
5   c   15
6   d   16
#Let us say i want to create 2 batches. The following dataframes are how i want my batches to look like
batch_1 = (pd.DataFrame({'id':['a','b'],'col1':[1,2]}),pd.DataFrame({'id':['a','a','b'],'col1':[10,11,12]}))
print(batch_1[0])
    id  col1
0   a   1
1   b   2
print(batch_1[1])
  id  col1
0  a    10
1  a    11
2  b    12
batch_2 = (pd.DataFrame({'id':['c','d'],'col1':[3,4]}),pd.DataFrame({'id':['c','c','c','d'],'col1':[13,14,15,16]}))
print(batch_2[0])
id  col1
0  c     3
1  d     4

print(batch_2[1])
 id  col1
0  c    13
1  c    14
2  c    15
3  d    16
```

Comment: Is merging the two csvs together an option?

Comment: The thing is I might have more than 2 CSVs with 2 or more of them containing multiple rows per ```store_id``` . Merging the datasets would create a cartesian product and then once the batch is in memory I would have to separate them, remove duplicates etc out since I want to run different networks on them and merge the different networks only at the end; in the final fully connected layer